# R - Passing two variables to a function using lapply

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have a function looking like this:

```
Func_Daily <- function(DATAdir, DATE, RERUN){
  sum_dbefore <- Func_day_before(DATE)
  files <- Func_getFiles(DATE)
  if(length(files) > 0){
    data <- mclapply(files, function(x) Func_data_read(x), mc.cores = nCores)
    print(data)
  }
}
```

The main program passes the needed variables to `Func_Daily()`. `Func_Daily()` gets the files inside a folder from the function `Func_getFiles()` and passes that to the function `Func_data_read()` to read and alter each file inside that folder. 
The problem now is, that I have another function that calculates a value (`sum_dbefore`) and I will need that inside the `Func_data_read()` function:

```
Func_data_read <- function(file){
  if(length(file) > 0){
    data <- lf_getNetCDF(file)
    data$RR[1] <- data$RR[1]+sum_dbefore
    data$RR_acc <- cumsum(data$RR)
  }else{
    print(paste("no files on", DATE))
  }
  return(data)
}
```

Is there a way inside lapply to pass that value together with `files` to `Func_data_read()` to use both variables inside the function and get the value back to save it to data in `Func_Daily`?
I guess there is an easy way to do that using lapply, but so far I couldn't figure out how. If possible I don't want to rebuild the whole set up as it is connected to a few more functions inside the script. So using lapply to pass `sum_dbefore` and `files` and use them inside `Func_data_read()` would be my preferred way of doing it.

Comment: Did you try `mcmapply()`?

Comment: No haven't. I will have a look at `mapply()`

Comment: @BallerNacken: if `sum_dbefore` is **not the same** for all `files`, then @hrbrmstr comment about `mcmapply()` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the following should do it assuming `sum_before` is the **same** for all `files`:

```
Func_Daily <- function(DATAdir, DATE, RERUN){
  sum_dbefore <- Func_day_before(DATE)
  files <- Func_getFiles(DATE)
  if(length(files) > 0){
    data <- mclapply(files, Func_data_read, sum_dbefore = sum_dbefore, mc.cores = nCores)
    print(data)
  }
}
```

with `Fun_data_read` defined before it

```
Func_data_read <- function(file, sum_dbefore) {
  if(length(file) > 0){
    data <- lf_getNetCDF(file)
    data$RR[1] <- data$RR[1]+sum_dbefore
    data$RR_acc <- cumsum(data$RR)
  } else {
    print(paste("no files on", DATE))
  }
  return(data)
}
```

In the above, we add an input argument for `sum_dbefore` to `Fun_data_read(...)` and we pass `sum_dbefore` to `Fun_data_read()` through `mclapply` as the "optional arguments to FUN". See the [documentation for `mclapply`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/multicore/docs/mclapply) under **USAGE**:

> mclapply(X, FUN, ..., mc.preschedule = TRUE, mc.set.seed = TRUE,
>            mc.silent = FALSE, mc.cores = getOption("cores"), mc.cleanup = TRUE)

and **Arguments**

> ... optional arguments to FUN

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that, but like this: `data <- mclapply(files, function(x) Davis_RR_acc_read(x), sum_dbefore = sum_dbefore, mc.cores = nCores)` with `Davis_RR_acc_read <- function(file, sum_dbefore)` but that gave me an unused argument error. Your version works though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I've understood you correctly and `sum_dbefore` is a single constant for all `files`, then you shouldn't need to explicitly pass this to `Func_data_read(x)` within `mclapply`.

When `sum_dbefore` is encountered within `Func_data_read(x)`, R will search for this variable in the function's enclosing environment. If it isn't there, then it will search the enclosing environment of the enclosing environment, and so on. A good explanation can be found [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs).

For example,

```
library(parallel)
q <- 10
mclapply(1:3, function(x) sqrt(x + q), mc.cores = 1)

# [[1]]
# [1] 3.316625
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3.464102
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3.605551
```

Your code should work as it is.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. But `sum_dbefore` is always changing. Depending on multiple factors.

Comment: According you your code above, `sum_dbefore` is computed only once using `Func_day_before(DATE)`, before `Func_data_read` is called within `mclapply` - i.e. it is the same for all values of `files` for any single execution of `Func_Daily`. So within any one call of `Func_Daily`, `sum_dbefore` is **not** changing. So the above code should work.

Comment: BTW: I'm assuming that `sum_dbefore` is a single number.

Comment: What I posted is only a part of the code. All the functions are nested in a few loops and those will change the values for `sum_dbefore` and a lot of different values.

Comment: @AlexIoannides: actually, I don't think `sum_dbefore` needs to be a single number. Indeed, your approach will work unless the elements of `sum_dbefore` needs to be somehow "paired" with elements of `files`. In this case, both of our approaches will not work and `mcmapply` is needed. My approach, however, gives added flexibility in that the variable name needs not be the same inside and outside the applied function. This provides encapsulation and reuse of that function in possibly another context.